# Iterating quadratic polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $p(z) = z^2+6z+1$ and $\varphi(z)=z+3$ and I am supposed to calculate $p^{3}(-1)$ given the formula $p=\varphi^{-1}\circ f\ \circ \varphi$.

I know that $p^{n}=\varphi^{-1}\circ f^{n}\ \circ \varphi$ and I understand the fundamental concept when applying hese mappings but I don't know how to apply the formula in practice. How do I go about taking the inverse of the function $\varphi$? Ultimately, I should arrive at a function of the form $z^2+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, if a function $\phi$ does something to a number, then the inverse $\psi=\phi^{-1}$ undoes it.

In your example $\phi$ takes $z$ and adds $3$ to get $z+3$.  If you start with $z+3$ and want to undo this operation to get back to $z$, you have to subtract $3$.  Therefore the inverse is $\psi(z)=z-3$.  To check this, if you start with $z$ then apply $\phi$ and $\psi$ in either order , you get $z$ back again:
$$\phi(\psi(z))=\psi(z)+3=(z-3)+3=z$$
and
$$\psi(\phi(z))=\phi(z)-3=(z+3)-3=z\ .$$

Comment: Okay, so would this be the equivalent of taking the conjugate, e.g. $\varphi^{-1}=\overline{\varphi}$?

Comment: No, $z-3$ is not the same as $\overline z$ is it?

Comment: Dumb question, sorry. I know better.

Comment: Why is it more convenient to use this than just calculating $p^{3}$? This seems like it would take longer

Comment: Maybe $f$ is easier to calculate than $p$?  I haven't worked out what $f$ is myself so not sure.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is part of the iteration
$$
z_{n+1}=z_n^2+6z_n+1.
$$
Completing the square one is lead to consider the transformed sequence $w_n=z_n+3$ so that
$$
w_{n+1}=z_{n+1}+3=(z_n)+3)^2-9+4=w_n^2-5,
$$
which is what the claim amounts to.